# Keeping lines in vim with certain number of columns

Tags: multiple-lines

I have a large file which have some corrupt lines like this

```
0.6 8   379699  730 0.999769    0.802075    0.912155
0.6 8   379699  731 0.999698    0.8181070.8 8   377999  0   0.674844
0.765493    0.900248
0.8 8   377999  1   0.835223    0.913123    0.883744
0.8 8   377999  1   0.816537    1   0.852433
```

The file ideally should look like

```
0.6 8   379699  730 0.999769    0.802075    0.912155
0.6 8   379699  731 0.999698    0.818107    nan
0.8 8   377999  0   0.674844    0.765493    0.900248
0.8 8   377999  1   0.835223    0.913123    0.883744
0.8 8   377999  1   0.816537    1   0.852433
```

I thought that a simple (lazy) way to fix this problem might be to just delete any lines which don't have 7 columns. Can this be done? I was looking into using `awk -F' ' '` to obtain the number of columns in each line. is there a better way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to "find" the start of a new line and add a newline? `:%s/\d\zs\d\.\d/\r&/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete lines without seven columns? Sure...

```
:v/\v^\S+(\s+\S+){6}$/d
```

[`:vglobal`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:v), the "inverse" [`:global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:g) command, looks for all lines that *don't* match the search criteria and then [`d`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:d)eletes them.

The search criteria is

- `\v` : Use "very magic mode"
- `^` :  Beginning of line.
- `\S+` : Some non-whitespace.
- `(\s+\S+){6}` : Six occurrences of whitespace followed by non-whitespace.
- `$` : End of line.

Now this is a little loose in that you wouldn't want to run it against mixed text. I deliberately made it simple and tuned to the example text provided. If the columns, for example, are separated by a single tab the pattern could reflect that more strict criteria. Let me know if you need help with that kind of refinement.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: @Thomas Good to hear! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the awk solution: `:%!awk 'NF == 7'`. The condition says to only run the action (default when omitted `print`) when the number of fields is 7. By default awk's fields are just whitespace (not including newlines) separated.

It can also be nice to format the file a bit to glance at the columns: `:%!column -t`.

Of course, these both require some kind of *nix-like system or utilities.